# Do $(1+\varepsilon)$- bilipschitz maps preserve angles?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a bilipschitz map such that $$ \frac{1}{1+\varepsilon} d(x,y) \leq d(f(x),f(y)) \leq (1+ \varepsilon) d(x,y)  $$

for some $\varepsilon>0$ and the standart metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$. 
If $\varepsilon= 0$ we have an honest isometry, which preserves angles in the euclidean space.

**Does an $(1+\varepsilon)$ bilipschitz map almost preserve angles?**

In the sense that if $\triangle ABC$ is a triangle and $\alpha$ is the angle between the sides $AB$ and $BC$, then we have $  \vert \tilde{\alpha}- \alpha \vert < E(\varepsilon)$ where $\tilde{\alpha}$ denotes the angle between the sides $f(A)f(B)$ and $f(B)f(C)$ and $E(\varepsilon)$ is some error term satisfying $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0 } E(\varepsilon)=0$.

Here are my computations so far: 
By the cosine formula we have for a triangle with side lengths a,b,c
$$ \cos(\alpha)= \frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}{2 ab}$$
In the worst case scenario the angles $\alpha$ gets smaller if the side $c$ is shrunk by the maximal possible factor. That means

$$\frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}{2 ab} \leq \frac{a^2 + b^2 - \frac{1}{(1+\varepsilon)^2} c^2}{2 ab}  = \frac{((1 + \varepsilon)a)^2 + ((1 + \varepsilon)b)^2 -  c^2}{2 ((1 + \varepsilon)a)((1 + \varepsilon)b)}  $$
Now the worst thing we can do considering the formula is to stretch the sides a,b with the maximal possible factor i.e 
$$\cos(\alpha)= \frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}{2 ab} \leq \frac{((1 + \varepsilon)^2a)^2 + ((1 + \varepsilon)^2b)^2 -  c^2}{2 ((1 + \varepsilon)^2a)((1 + \varepsilon)^2b)} = \frac{a^2 + b^2 -  (\frac{c}{(1+\varepsilon)^2})^2}{2 ab}   $$

Therefore the worst what can happen to an angle is that the opposite side is multiplied by a factor close to $1$. From my Intuition I would say that does not disturb the angles too much. However I am missing the rigorous argument.